# Plot two data frames in one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this two data frames df and df1 where

```
B2B_1 = {'Month': ['10/2018','11/2018','12/2018','01/2019','02/2019','03/2019'],
        'B2B': [200,400, 250,
                100,120,200]]
        }
B2C_1 = {'Month': ['10/2018','11/2018','12/2018','01/2019','02/2019','03/2019'],
        'B2C': [200,400, 250,
                100,120,200]
        }
```

```
df=pd.DataFrame(B2B_1)
df1=pd.DataFrame(B2C_1)
```

And I didn't know how to plot these two data frames in one plot where axis is based on "Month"

Comment: try this:`pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1).plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` plotting functions have the `ax` parameter in them; if you pass an e.g. matplotlib axis instance to it, it will do its plotting on that axis. So

```py
# make a figure and an axis 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 7))

# plot desired quantities; note the `ax=ax` in both
df.plot(x="Month", y="B2B", ax=ax)
df1.plot(x="Month", y="B2C", ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two DataFrame something like this code

```
B2B_1 = {'Month': ['10/2018','11/2018','12/2018','01/2019','02/2019','03/2019'],
        'B2B': [200,400, 250,
                100,120,200]
        }
B2C_1 = {'Month': ['10/2018','11/2018','12/2018','01/2019','02/2019','03/2019'],
        'B2C': [200,400, 250,
                100,120,200]
        }
  
df=pd.DataFrame(B2B_1)
df1=pd.DataFrame(B2C_1)

x=df['Month']
x1=df["B2B"]
y=df1['Month']
y1=df1["B2C"]  
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.bar(x,x1,label="Month")
plt.bar(y,y1,label="Month")
plt.title("Data")
plt.legend(title="Data")
plt.show()
```

Using that code help to plot the two dataframe easy